# Is it possible to create a CompositeIndex of CosmosDB with ARM template

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

I find instructions for using ARM templates to create or make changes to CosmosDB, but none of them contain instructions on how to add a CompositeIndex to the template. I have also heard it is not supported in the template and has to be done with PowerShell or Azure CLI script, but have not been able to find a supporting content on the net. Can someone please shed light on this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy Looks like no ARM support. This is why I see that ARM in many cases is not best way to do I would rather use Powershell or Azure cli

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but according to the Microsoft.DocumentDB resource provider docs / template reference there is a Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/containers resource which may give you what you need.

Every container has an **IndexingPolicy** in the template schema, which has an array of **IncludedPath** objects which themselves have an array of **Index** objects as follows:

```
        "includedPaths": [
          {
            "path": "string",
            "indexes": [
              {
                "dataType": "string",
                "precision": "integer",
                "kind": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

It's treated as a separate resource from the database / account altogether.  You may want to add this resource to your template with an appropriate dependsOn value to ensure it's deployed after your database.

You can add multiple paths therefore making a composite index.

Full schema is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/2015-04-08/databaseaccounts/apis/databases/containers

If this doesn't do it, you may want to look at this too as the schema docs may be out of date and compositeIndexes may be supported:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy#composite-indexing-policy-examples

Comment: yeah it should work but I cannot find it anywhere in the documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/2019-08-01/databaseaccounts#DatabaseAccountCreateUpdateProperties

Comment: clearly does not support compositeindex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/2015-04-08/databaseaccounts/apis/databases/containers#indexingpolicy-object